# Use define_method in parent class with dynamic content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming

I'm trying to achieve something that is for sure possible but I'm not able to put it into to find it from the docuemntation.

In a nutshell, I would like to define methods dynamically:

Initial point:

```rb
class Foo < Bar
  def baz
    RecordLoader.for(Baz).load(object.baz_id)
  end

  def qux
    RecordLoader.for(Quz).load(object.qux_id)
  end
end

class Bar
end
```

I would like to be able to change it to

```rb
class Foo < Bar
  record_loader_for :baz
  record_loader_for :qux
end

class Bar
  def self.record_loader_for(attribute)
    define_method attribute.to_s do
      # What is missing here?
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can use the value of attribute to write something like

```rb
RecordLoader.for(attribute.to_s.classify.constantize). # <- attribute is local to the class
            .load(object.send("#{attribute.to_s}_id")) # <- object is local to the instance
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with `class_eval` and generate your method into string:

```rb
  def self.record_loader_for(attribute)
    class_eval <<~RUBY, __FILE__ , __LINE__ + 1
      def #{attribute}
        RecordLoader.for(#{attribute.to_s.classify}).load(#{attribute}_id)
      end
    RUBY
  end
```

but in fact, `define_method` should work too, ruby will save closure from the method call:

```rb
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'ostruct'

class RecordLoader
  def self.for(cls)
    new(cls)
  end

  def initialize(cls)
    @cls = cls
  end

  def load(id)
    puts "loading #{@cls} id #{id}"
  end
end

class Baz; end

class Bar
  def object
    OpenStruct.new(baz_id: 123, qux_id:321)
  end

  def self.record_loader_for(attribute)
    define_method attribute.to_s do
      RecordLoader.for(attribute.to_s.classify.constantize).
        load(object.send("#{attribute.to_s}_id"))
    end
  end
end

class Foo < Bar
  record_loader_for :baz
  record_loader_for :qux
end

Foo.new.baz
```

`class_eval` is slower to define method, but resulting method executes faster and does not keep references to original closure context, `define_method` is the opposite - defines faster, but method runs slower.